# How to create MSQM Trigger Rules using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, msmq

I can create MSMQ queues using the following powershell command: `New-MsmqQueue`

I can't find a way to create Trigger Rules via powershell (`Computer Management > Services and Applications > Message Queuing > Triggers > Rules`)

Is it possible, and if not, what's the best workaround if I want them created just by running powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not only it's impossible to accomplish in Powershell, but you also won't be able to manage your triggers via C#.  The workaround I came up with is by directly modifying underlying registry key structure.  The keys you want to add are located here:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Triggers\Data\
```